# How do I solve TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, candlestick-chart, plotly-python

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
y = yf.download( tickers = "MSFT", period = "1y", interval = "1d" )

df = pd.DataFrame(y)
df = df.reset_index()
df["Date"] = df['Date'].dt.date # now date is not an index rather a separate column.

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],open=df['Open'],high=df['High'],low=df['Low'],close=df['Close'])])
fig.show()
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
runfile('xx.py', wdir='folderpath')

[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "something.py", line 53, in <module>
    close=df['Close']))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\__init__.py", line 46998, in __init__
    super(Ohlc, self).__init__("ohlc")

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4522, in __init__
    super(BaseTraceHierarchyType, self).__init__(plotly_name, **kwargs)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: Can you show the imports to your code as well? I'm assuming pd is the Pandas library, but what is `go` and `yf`?

Comment: I have updated it, thanks

Comment: A heads up, you have a typo in your code. You'll need to use this line of code ```fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],open=df['Open'],high=df['High'],low=df['Low'],close=df['Close']))```. Is this your issue?

Comment: So I just ran your code - with my modified line of code - and it worked correctly. I'm also working on a Mac. I'm not sure the exact error, but perhaps update your packages? ```pip3 install -U plotly yfinance ```

Comment: Wow, Amazing, the error is gone however it still wont plot even tho I updated plotly